# How to keep functions and triggers updated after renaming tables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

What is the correct way of handling PostgreSQL triggers and functions so that their table references are automatically updated every time those tables are changed or updated?
For example after changing the table's name or moving it into a different schema.

Comment: You have to do it by hand and hope that you don't forget anything.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe About forgetting anything, there certainly is some system table query that lets you search all defined functions :-)

Comment: @Bergi Of course, `pg_proc`, but there is no automatic way to determine which function uses which table.